# Convert generic T into System.Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have a list of `Enum`s as an `IEnumerable<T>` and I need to loop on each item and get its description like this:

```
IEnumerable<T> values = (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
foreach (Enum value in values)
{
    String mylist = Common.MyExtensions.getEnumDescription(value);
}

...

public static string getEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =    (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

    if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        return attributes[0].Description;
    }
    else
        return value.ToString();
}
```

This produces an error at the foreach section

> cannot convert "T" to System.Enum.

Isn't `IEnumerable` a list of `System.Enum` in the first place? 
What sort of cast can do the trick?

Comment: Shouldn't Enum be T?

Comment: Maybe try without casting. Like this: var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));

Comment: Where is enum variable? Use that instead of T.

Comment: The collection returned from Enum.GetValues is not a collection of Enums but a collection of ints (most probably).

Answer (score 9):

One way to do the cast is:

```
Enum enumValueError = (Enum)value;
//compiler error: Cannot convert type 'xxx' to 'System.Enum'
Enum enumValueNoError = value as Enum; 
//no error, but enumValueNoError will be null if value is not an Enum
```

Comment: Alternatively [`(int)(object)value`](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/28060.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

> Isn't IEnumerable a list of System.Enum in first place ? What sort of Cast can do the trick ?

Yes but compiler can't make sure this. `T` can be anything at runtime. In situations like this you usually use generic type constraints but `where T : Enum` is not valid, so what you can do is:

1. Don't make your method generic, change the parameter type to `Enum` if you wanna work with Enums only
2. Use `where T : struct` constraint to at least make sure `T` is a value type and check if the type is `Enum` inside of your method, if it's not throw an exception etc. (this is not recommended)

Comment: For your first solution: it would need some more work: `Enum.GetValues(t)` where `t` is a run-time `Type` instance, cannot be cast to `Enum[]`. For your second solution: that doesn't tell the OP how to get rid of the compile-time error about a conversion between `T` and `Enum`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your looking for something like this (changed the implementation a bit):

```
public enum Test
{
    [Description("This")]
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetEnumDescription<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    if (!type.IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("Only Enum types allowed");

    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>())
    {
        yield return getEnumDescription(value);
    }
}

public string getEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

    if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        return attributes[0].Description;
    }
    else
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

And the call will look like:

```
var desc = GetEnumDescription<Test>(); // "This", "B", "C", "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the type T that you're already working with...

```
IEnumerable<T> values = (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
foreach (T value in values)
{
    String mylist = Common.MyExtensions.getEnumDescription(value);
}
```

You will also have to make getEnumDesciption generic as well.

Comment: then the same error will occur at different place: `getEnumDescription(value);`

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach(var e in values)
{
    if(e is Enum)
    {
        Enum eAsEnum = (Enum)e;
        String mylist = Common.MyExtensions.getEnumDescription(eAsEnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will still give the same error at the cast `Enum eAsEnum = (Enum)e;
`