# How to get an IEnumerable<string> of enum values attributes?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a `StringValue` attribute for enums values, so I could attach a description to each value:

```
public class StringValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public StringValueAttribute(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

And that is how I use it:

```
enum Group
{
    [StringValue("Computer Science")]
    ComputerScience,

    [StringValue("Software Engineering")]
    SoftwareEngineering,

    // ... additional values follow.
}
```

I have a method that retrieves the `StringValue` given the enum value:

```
public static string GetStringValue(Enum value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(type.ToString());
    StringValueAttribute[] attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

    string stringValue = null;
    if (attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        stringValue = attributes[0].Value;
    }

    return stringValue;
}
```

I want to have another method that gets an enum (the enum itself, not a value) and retrieves an `IEnumerable` using the `GetStringValue` method. I am not sure how to accomplish that. How could a method like this look like?

---

**Edit:** this question is not a duplicate of *[How to get C# Enum description from value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2650080/3744182)*. I know how to get an enum attribute value, and I actually have a method in the question that does exactly that. My question is how to enumerate all the attributes in an enum.

Comment: You mean you want a generic method `GetStringValues<TEnum>()`?

Comment: You can use the existing `DescriptionAttribute` instead of your own custom attribute. For the enumeraiton, `Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)).Cast<EnumType>().Select(/*call your method*/)`

Comment: @dbc - Something like that. However, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27101267/1925272) it is suggested to not make such methods generic.

Comment: Also, typo: `FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());` -- you're passing `type.ToString()`, not `value.ToString()`

Comment: @EdPlunkett - Thanks. I do not understand: should I write `value.ToString()` instead?

Comment: @EdPlunkett - I am not able to make your code work. Here is what I wrote: `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Group)).Cast<Group>().Select(g => EnumsUtility.GetStringValue(g));`. also, could you write it in an answer?

Comment: @Vikhram - please read the question. It's really not the same.

Comment: @Sipo That works for me. dbc has just posted essentially the solution I was about to suggest, so I saved myself some typing and just upvoted him.

Comment: @Vikhram - my question is not how to get a custom attribute from an enum, the question is how to enumerate all of these attributes.

Comment: @Sipo That question and its accepted answer do actually cover everything needed for your answer: If you can get all the values for an enum type, and if you can get a particular attribute for each value, the rest is just putting it all in a loop.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - [In the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), Microsoft writes that the `DescriptionAttribute` should be used with *properties and events*. Should I really use it for enum values?

Comment: @Sipo It’s just metadata, and it’s often used on enum values. There isn’t any harm that can be done by it. Of course, by the same token there’s no harm in writing your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is with a generic, though you could always pass in an instance of your specific `Enum`, get its type, then return the `StringValue` values for all its values:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetStringValues<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
            .Cast<Enum>()
            .Select(e => e.GetStringValue())
            .ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetStringValuesOfType(Enum value)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(value.GetType())
            .Cast<Enum>()
            .Select(e => e.GetStringValue())
            .ToList();
    }

    public static string GetStringValue(this Enum value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());
        StringValueAttribute[] attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

        string stringValue = null;
        if (attributes.Length > 0)
        {
            stringValue = attributes[0].Value;
        }

        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- There is no `where TEnum : Enum` constraint in c#.  Restricting `TEnum` to be `struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable` is *mostly* sufficient.
- That being said, there is a cunning trick to apply an `enum` constraint which is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1416660/3744182) to [Enum type constraints in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1331739/3744182) by [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks).  (I didn't use it in this answer though since it's really very cunning.)
- As noted in @EdPlunkett's comment you need to pass `value.ToString()` to `type.GetField()` since you're getting the field corresponding to that specific incoming `enum` value.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SDgMak)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var item in GetStringNames<Group>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
public static string GetStringValue(Enum value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());
    StringValueAttribute[] attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

    string stringValue = null;
    if (attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        stringValue = attributes[0].Value;
    }

    return stringValue;
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetStringNames<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    if (type.IsEnum == false)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an Enum type");
    }

    var values = type.GetEnumValues();

    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        yield return GetStringValue((Enum)item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I chose @dbc's answer because it suited my program better, but it seems like your answer is good as well.